# Run-time error 1004 while using dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba

I have 15 names in column A. While trying to  ReDim and populate an already declared array, and extracting the elements (names) into column E, the following code gave me hiccups saying that it was run-time error 1004 (application-defined or object-defined error).

```
Dim f() as string

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim Preserve f(Finalrow - 1)

For i = 0 To Finalrow - 1
    f(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) ''''This line causes the glitch (error 1004)
Next

For i = 0 To Finalrow - 1
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = f(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop variable ***i*** starts with 0; this kills the `Cells()` function.
*(there may be other errors)*

Comment: \*...since there is no column number zero.

Answer (score 1):

Is this academic exercise?

If not then one can easily use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FinalRow As Long
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("E1:E" & FinalRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & FinalRow).Value
End Sub
```